# In android listview data is getting multiple times when i'm going back how can i eleminate it?

Tags: android, listview

I'm having 2 views:

1. Listview
2. Details of list item

When I run my app first it'll show `ListView` then when I selected the
item from `ListView` it'll enter into the next view called details of
list item. Now when I'm going back to the `ListView` the items of the
list are appearing multiple times. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

In the below shown way I'm adding data to ArrayAdapter.

```
MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(SampleActivity.this, R.layout.citieslist, scity);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

MyArrayAdapter is as follows...

```
private class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] items;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int
            textViewResourceId, String[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return
                position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.citieslist, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
        tv.setText(items[position]);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you asked so many questions and not accepted a single answer?

Comment: now can u say the answer for my query

Comment: It's probably your adapter.  Please post the code

Comment: see the code and give reply boss

Answer (score 0):

I'd try 3 things:

1. Remove the setTextFilterEnabled line.  Unless you're doing something specifically with the filtering that I don't know about.
2. You're passing in the context but not saving it.  Save it to a class variable and use it for #3.
3. Change the inflate line of your getView() method of the adapter to:

   ```
   if (v == null) {                
       v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.citieslist, parent, false);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is two possibilities,

one:

when you go back from detail view to listview page,

if you use "startActivity(intent)",  replace with "finish()".

two:
initialize listview "scity" in "onCreateView()"